# How to configure Google Ads iOS campaign for Expo React Native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, google-ads-api

I've built an app with Expo and successfully published it in Apple's App Store and Google's Play Store. Included in it is AdMob for running ads in the app, and Firebase for analytics.

Now I'm using Google Ads to promote it, so added two campaigns, one for Android and one for iOS. The Android campaign has been running well for the past few weeks, but the iOS has done nothing at all (no impressions, no costs).

I tried adding a new conversion action for tracking `first_open` event from Firebase. I can see in Firebase and Google Analytics that that event has been tracked for iOS. But, the status of the action in Google Ads has been on `No recent conversions` for two weeks now, so that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

I tried following the [instructions for React Native Google Mobile Ads](https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads#enable-skadnetwork-to-track-conversions-ios), adding the `sk_ad_network_items` into my `app.json`. Also made sure the project settings in Firebase are set up correctly.

Am I missing something? Anyone got this working?

Comment: Hello! I've faced the same question.. did you find any solution? I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Unfortunately not, but haven't tried to look for a solution in a while. Will post it if I do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked to track iOS conversions for me in Expo.

In app.json include the sk_ad_network_items. But, additionally, include it in app.config.js under expo > ios > infoPlist > SKAdNetworkItems.